# how to print like 1,2,5,10,17,26,37,50,65

Tags: php

In a small project I would link to print 1,2,5,10,17,26,37,50,65.This number is increased by an odd number like 1,3,5,7,9,11,13.

I've been unable to find any way to print.

any suggest?

```
$counter = 0;
$maxCount = 1000;
$sum = 0;
while($counter <=$maxCount)
{
    if ($counter % 2 != 0)
    {
        $sum += $counter;
    }
    echo $sum . "<br>";
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: you are on the right way. but you should start with $sum=1, only output when incrementing, and output before incrementing to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `while()` loop,

```
$start = $interva1 = 1;
$maxCount = 100;
while($start < $maxCount){
    echo $start . " ";
    $start += $interva1;
    $interva1 += 2;
}
```

- `$start` is the number you want to start the sequence with
- `$interval` is the odd number to be added in each iteration of the loop

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by using a for loop and increment by 2. If you start on an odd number as gap, the gap will always stay an odd number.

```
$sum = 1;
$maxGap = 1000;

for ($gap = 1; $gap <= $maxGap; $gap += 2) {
    echo $sum . "<br />";
    $sum += $gap;
}
```